# Why is FFMPEG not using hardware decoding on Android when using the h264_mediacodec decoder?

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to use FFMPEG in C++ using the `h264_mediacodec` decoder to decode a video on Android. The frame I receive is `AV_PIX_FMT_NV12` instead of `AV_PIX_FMT_MEDIACODEC`, which implies that the hardware decoding isn't working.

I followed [this example](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/hw__decode_8c_source.html#l00049) to set up the decoder. I tried it on Windows with `h264_cuvid` and it works as expected, but on Android using mediacodec, I can't get the frame in the expected format.

Comment: For android, they have not implemented `mediCodec` encoder thus hardware support is unavailable. they just have a decoder for `mediacodec`.